# CRUD knockout js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, knockout.js

I know this is too much to ask but I cannot find any good tutorials on what I am doing.
I am getting data from the database and using foreach on the html page to show the fields. Like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/learnKO.js?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');?>" ></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">1</th>
                        <th class="text-center">2</th>
                        <th class="text-center">3</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: alldata">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.net_amount "></span></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.vat_amount"></span></td>
                            <td>

                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.editItem">Edit</button>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.acceptItem">Accept</button> 
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.cancelItem">Cancel</button> 
                            </td>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

My js file includes a simple function, which gets the data like this.

```
self.alldata = ko.observableArray();

        self.viewAllInvoice = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/learn_Ko/' ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(invoices) {
            self.alldata.removeAll();
            $.each(invoices, function (index, invoice) {

                    self.alldata.push(invoice);
                });
        })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        };
    self.viewAllInvoice();
```

And I am using phpcode igniter for getting the data. Here is how I get from the controller and model.

```
public function learn_Ko(){


        $this->load->model('invoice_page');
        $result = $this->invoice_page->getAllInvoice();
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
         $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));


    }
```

And here is the model

```
public function getAllInvoice(){
        $query ='SELECT * FROM invoice';

        $query = $this->db->query($query);
                $result = $query->result();
        return $result; 
    }
```

What I want to do is just edit the table and the edited data to be stored in the database. Please do guide me in steps since I tried a lot of different tutorials but couldn't do it. I provided everything here so I am sure I am not missing anything.
This is the table pic 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a JavaScript CRUD app, I'd use an OData service in the server (I'm sure there must be some implementations in PHP, for example see: [How to create an Odata Service using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836764/how-to-create-an-odata-service-using-php)) and the wonderful [breeze.js](http://www.getbreezenow.com/breezejs) library.

Breeze.js handles all the CRUD stuff, and communication with the OData service in a very easy and powerful way. And get ons very well with knockout: you simply have to load the konockout library before breeze, so that breeze detects it. If you do so, breeze will generate observable properties automatically for you from the data recevied from the OData service. And allows to validate, track changes, send changes in a batch and many more things.

Comment: I just want to do it with basic knockout js. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Then, please, learn knockout, instead of asking. There are good tutorials to learn it. Don't expect someone to teach you. I thought you was looking for a better architecture, not looking for "free teaching". You can run the oficial tutorial, and look for many other interesting resources on the web. If you have a concrete problem, please, ask again, and you'll probaby get help from some (or from me).